# codesign plugins for mac app

Tags: xcode, xcode5, code-signing, codesign

Following this [article](http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/), I'm running codesign for all frameworks. However, I'm still getting a codesign error with plugins.

```
/.../Applications/MyApp.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /.../MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/Flash Player.plugin
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

How should I add codesign command for plugins? Tried various directories/files, but didn't work:

```
codesign --verbose --force --sign "$IDENTITY" "$PLUGINS_LOCATION/Flash Player.plugin"
```

Comment: Forgive our ignorance... What article?

Comment: @jww it's linked in the opening line: http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/

Answer (score 0):

We had to codesign the plugin separately:

```
codesign --deep --verbose --force --sign "Developer ID Application" Plugins/Flash\ Player.plugin
```